# No modeling project option in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed vs2010 and I want to create modelling project but find no option for the modelling project option. Can any body help what is wrong with my situation

Answer (score 3):

You need the Ultimate Edition to do this. Check your edition via Help -> About.

A detailed comparison on which features are available in which edition can be found on the [product page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products).

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 Profession with RTM release can i create a  modeling project with this relase? or I have to get a copy of vs2010 Ultimate Edition as it is the only way?

Comment: Yes the architecture tools (like modelling projects) are only available in the architect edition. For a comprehensive feature comparison, view the link I edited into my answer.

Comment: I have installed the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition and create a modeling project. I Have created a class named as Deal_Entity and defined all the attributes, now I want to set the Property methods against those attributes in class Diagram. However, in the vs modeling project i see only 2 categories. i.e Attributes and Operation in the Deal_Entity class. It is unlike vs2008 class diagram where we could define the class property methods along with attributes and operations. Is there a solution to get a way with it.

Comment: Unlike the class diagram available in all editions of the visual studio (except the express afaik), the modelling project class diagram is a "real" UML diagram. UML class diagrams does not know the concept of properties, so you have the attributes instead. Attributes are basically properties in C# because you usually design no field members in your UML class diagram (it would be too detailed). But you design events as attributes too (basically events are fields in C#).

Comment: Could you please add some give detail about this topic

Answer (score 1):

In case you own ULTIMATE edition but the template does not show up nevertheless, you may try to reset your collection of installed templates:

On a administrative command line, navigate to

```
<Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE
```

and execute

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx